# Building FlywayDB from Source fails finding sqlline 1.1.8 dependency

Tags: maven, flyway

I am having difficulty building FlywayDB from source based on the latest 4.0 code (as of 3/14/2016).

The setup and build instructions have options to disable/skip the database specific build/tests/platform-assemblies which I have tried.

Per https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html,  -DskipTests only skips execution, not compile.  I tried both -DskipTests and -Dmaven.test.skip=true with no change in the compile error.

So, it still seems to have a non-test dependency that requires sqlline:sqlline:1.1.8 (which is no longer available in Maven Central) and Maven isn't giving me the dependency that is requiring sqlline without errors.

Anyone have ideas as to why it won't build even without tests?

I've included abbreviated output below of each command:

C:\Flyway> **mvn -version**

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T09:41:47-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Dropbox\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_74, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

C:\Flyway> **mvn install -InstallableDBTest -CommercialDBTest -CommandlinePlatformAssemblies**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
 ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flyway-core 0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 is missing, no dependency information available
  ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.643 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-14T11:33:19-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/435M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flyway-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 in nexus
 ...

\Flyway> **mvn clean compile -DskipTests -Dmaven.test.skip=true**
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
   ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flyway-core 0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 is missing, no dependency information available
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.000 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-14T11:20:34-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flyway-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 in nexus
   ...
```

C:\Flyway> **mvn install -DskipTests -Dmaven.test.skip=true**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
 ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flyway-core 0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 is missing, no dependency information available
  ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.643 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-14T11:33:19-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/435M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flyway-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 in nexus
 ...

\Flyway> **mvn clean compile -DskipTests -Dmaven.test.skip=true**
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
   ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flyway-core 0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 is missing, no dependency information available
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.000 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-14T11:20:34-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flyway-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 in nexus
   ...
```